# Creating a deep link for installing or starting the app

Tags: android, deep-linking, install-referrer

I use the following link to install the app from Google play and able to get the referrer value after installation through a InstallReferrer receiver.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sample.app&referrer=Zmlyc3RuYW1lP2xhc3RuYW1l
```

But the next time I click the link it takes me to the app page in Google play.

How can I create a deep link so that if the app is not installed it should takes us to the app page Google play or start the app if it is already installed?

Below is a sample deeplink I've created.

```
https://APP_CODE.app.goo.gl/?link= Zmlyc3RuYW1lP2xhc3RuYW1l&apn=com.sample.app&amv=40&afl=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sample.app&referrer=Zmlyc3RuYW1lP2xhc3RuYW1l
```

Is this a good deep link or Any any parameter should I add/delete to make it better?

Comment: Check this documentation about all app linking methods available on Android: https://simonmarquis.github.io/Android-App-Linking/

Comment: Thanks. The https://simonmarquis.github.io/Android-App-Linking/#market-scheme works well from a the device but when I click the same from the browser it is not redirecting anywhere. This is the format I've used - market://details?id=com.sample.app&url=link://example.com/action?param=Zmlyc3RuYW1lP2xhc3RuYW1l&referrer=Zmlyc3RuYW1lP2xhc3RuYW1l

Comment: You can use JavaScript to detect if you're on a desktop and use an https link instead

Comment: But if I'm sending an invitation email and click from the email this won't work.

Comment: Then try the play store url version

Comment: With play store url version, if the app is already installed and click the url again it is redirecting to the google play app page instead of going to the app

Comment: Does it open the web version of the play store or the app version? If it's the web version, your email client might block the play store AppLink....

Comment: Then you might need to host your own webpage with a redirect url...

Comment: It opens the play store app version.

Comment: Well it means that your app is not handling the url provided in the &url query param

Comment: Yes. I'm handling with this intent filter             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:scheme="link" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: I've tried with this app https://simonmarquis.github.io/Android-App-Linking/#play-store-url -- If app is installed and click again it is taking me to Google play app page

Comment: Awesome page/project @simon-marquis. Is market scheme still a legitimate way of deep linking? I can't find any documentation for it anywhere. The link you provided in your documentation seems out of date as it doesn't mention market scheme anywhere.

Comment: @spaceagestereo, thanks for spotting this issue. The Google documentation page is not the same for every language. In french, market scheme is still mentionned: https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play?hl=fr#android-app . From what is explained here, you should prefer market over http when you're inside an app (to avoid the browser I suppose). So it's safe to use.

Comment: Thanks for the response @simon-marquis. Your AppLink app works great with market scheme but I only get my apps Google Play Store page even if I have the app installed. I have market://details?id=com.app.my&url=myscheme://app.com/action?key=value. I have myscheme in an intent filter but feel I'm missing something. It sounds like I don't need a broadcast receiver until I want to handle pre-install scenario.

Comment: @spaceagestereo, the `url` query parameter must be url-encoded.